# prevent page to reload jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

The code is working fine for me if the page is completely loaded But the issue is if the page is in loading mode I click on the link it reloads again how I prevent it from reloading.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var key = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
    $('#loadingmessage').show();
    $.ajax({
      type : 'post',
      url : 'test.php',  
      data :  'key='+ key, 
      success : function(data) {
      $('.modal-body').html(data);
    },
    complete: function() {
      $('#loadingmessage').hide();
    }
  });
  return false;
 });
});
```

My Html is here

```
<a href='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' data-id='1:2:3:4'>UP</a>
```

If page is completey loaded and i click on this the ajax call is works fine but when page is loading if i clcik the page starts reloading again how i prevent it to reload.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Check Server Status</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="loadingmessage">Checking...</div>
                 </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Replace `$(document).ready(function()...` through `$(document).load(function()...?`. This should do the trick.

Comment: ok let me try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' data-id='1:2:3:4'>UP</a>`

Comment: anytime buddy!!